# How do you set CONTEXT_INFO = NULL?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I use `CONTEXT_INFO` to skip triggers as such:

```
IF CONTEXT_INFO() = 0x676E6F7468692073656175746F6E RETURN
```

and in my PROC:

```
IF CONTEXT_INFO() IS NOT NULL SET @CONTEXT_INFO = CONTEXT_INFO() -- to restore later
SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x676E6F7468692073656175746F6E
```

How do you set it back to NULL if you needed to?  `SET CONTEXT_INFO = NULL` does **not** work.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-context-info-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just use

```
SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x /*Gets padded with zeros when cast to binary(128)*/
```

You don't set it to `NULL`. If you look at

```
select context_info
from sys.sysprocesses
```

You will see that it is not `NULL` for any of the connections.

Comment: But before it is defined it is null:  select context_info()

Comment: @DanAndrews - If it is zeroed out `select context_info()` returns `NULL`. i.e. `SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x;select context_info()`

Comment: @MartinSmith I think the comment in your first statement is wrong, it seems like '0x' is treated as null but not padded out with zeroes, using '0x0' gives all zeroes and not null.   To save it for restoring the original value, this seems to work: `declare @originalContextInfo varbinary(128) = isnull(context_info(),0x)`

Comment: @JasonGoemaat - the comment specifically says `cast to binary(128)` not `varbinary`